# How do I Profile a Jupyter Cell and Rank it by Cumulative Time?

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter, one-hot-encoding

I'm using SciKit-Learn's [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html?highlight=onehotencoder#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) to encode some categorical features. However, the time complexity of the function seems to have an exponential dependence on the number of rows passed to it.

I would like to profile my code to figure out what's going on, particularly, I would like to use cumulative time to rank the profiler's output. I'm using Jupyter notebooks to write the code, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter has built in ["cell magics"](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html), one of those cell magics is the `prun` function.

To use it, you put a call to `prun` at the top of the cell. For example:

```
%%prun
YOUR-CODE-BELOW
```

The `%%` at the beginning of the command tells Jupyter that this is a Cell Magic, if you don't include this, you'll get a syntax warning. To rank by cumulative time, you use the `-s` option and pass it `"cumulative time"`:

```
%%prun -s "cumulative"
YOUR-CODE-BELOW
```

This will profile the code in your cell and show you the output in a pop-up box on the bottom of your screen.