# Why does SciKit-Learn's OneHotEncoder take so long on a Large Dataset?

Tags: scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, efficiency

I'm using an older version of SciKit-Learn, version 1.0.2, to try and `OneHotEncode` some data. My dataset is fairly large, 184 columns going to 311 after the `OneHotEncoding`, with ~500,000 rows. Despite this, I'm confident I could write code that `OneHotEncodes` my columns in a minute maximum.

Currently, SciKit-Learn's [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/1.0/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html?highlight=onehotencoder#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) is on 10 minutes and counting. Why is this code so slow? Is there anything I can do to speed it all up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `OneHotEncoder` in a Jupyter Notebook, you can use `%%prun -s "time"` to profile your code. See [How do I Profile a Jupyter Cell and Rank it by Cumulative Time?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/116545/how-do-i-profile-a-jupyter-cell-and-rank-it-by-cumulative-time/116546#116546) for more information.

Doing this with a subset of the rows shows that the function calls taking up the most time are inside the `_encode` module function from SciKit-Learn's `utils` sub-package.

[image]

Looking inside this module you can see that `_encode`'s `_check_unknown`, and `_extract_missing` contain inefficient list comprehensions, and this is most likely what's slowing you down.

If you want to create a `OneHotEncoding` of your data I suggest using Panda's [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) functionality, it's so much faster.

There are a couple of differences, `pd.get_dummies(...)` disregards any NaN values by default, this can be changed by switching `dummy_na=True`. It is also sometimes considered best practice to drop one of the categorical features as a column, as one of the columns can be represented by all zeros in the other columns. For more information on that try reading these articles: [dummy variable trap](https://www.learndatasci.com/glossary/dummy-variable-trap/), [does the dropped column matter?](https://towardsdatascience.com/drop-first-can-hurt-your-ols-regression-models-interpretability-4ca529cfb707)